# change display of rows into column using PIVOT in sql server

Tags: sql-server

This is my query:

```
select d.disposition, count(a.serialnumber) AS SUBTOTAL
FROM FADB a, FARepair b, Disposition d
WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND b.DispositionID = d.DispositionID 
GROUP BY d.Disposition
```

and this is the result :

```
Disposition    SUBTOTAL
   a             45
   b             100
   c             39
```

I need to convert these rows to columns using PIVOT function in sql server and this is what i want it to look like:

```
a   b    c 
45 100  39
```

Someone please help me to change the query statement, really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) function:

```
WITH Data AS (
    -- this is your actual query

    --select d.disposition, count(a.serialnumber) AS SUBTOTAL
    --FROM FADB a, FARepair b, Disposition d
    --WHERE a.ID = b.ID AND b.DispositionID = d.DispositionID 
    --GROUP BY d.Disposition

    -- this is a sample just to make up the example

    SELECT *
    FROM (
        VALUES ('a', 45), ('b', 100), ('c', 39)
    ) AS d (Disposition, SUBTOTAL)
)
SELECT *
FROM DATA
PIVOT ( AVG(SUBTOTAL) FOR Disposition IN ([a],[b],[c])) AS pvt
```

I used the AVG aggregation function. Since you have exactly one row per disposition, it doesn't really matter which aggregation function you use.